# Encode ASCII text

Tags: python

I tried to encode but not success.

```
text = "don\\u2019t think"
textencode = text.encode('utf-8').split(" ")
print textencode
```

The result still ['don\u2019t', 'think']

I tried to get ['don't', 'think']

Any suggestion?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I tried to get ['don't', 'think']

Comment: @ThanaDaray, you will never get that (with Python2) because printing a list calls `repr` on each item. You need to call `str` for each item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are using Python2. Is this what you are looking for?

```
>>> text = u"don\u2019t think"
>>> textencode = text.encode('utf-8').split(" ")
>>> print textencode[0]
don’t
```

Python3 handles the unicode objects much more nicely

```
>>> text = "don\u2019t think"
>>> textencode = text.split(" ")
>>> textencode
['don’t', 'think']
```

Comment: Or you can also use `from __future__ import unicode_literals` to get the Python3 behavior in Python2.

Comment: @Fenikso I cannot use that. If I use that, there are a lot error in my codes.

Comment: @ThanaDaray - Well, probably because you did not account for it from the beginning and most of your code expects `str` literals instead of `unicode` ones. But if you work with unicode literals a lot, like writing GUI in foreign language, using it from the beginning may come handy.

Answer (score -1):

In python 2.x

```
>>> text = u"don\u2019t think"
>>> textencode = text.encode('utf-8').split(" ")
>>> print textencode
['don\xe2\x80\x99t', 'think']
>>> print textencode[0]
don’t
```

Prefix 'u' before the double quotes.